# SQL - Pivot Column To Rows with Group By and Concat

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, string-aggregation, string-agg

I need to traspose a column into a row ( by concatenating it) with group by...

using : sql server 2019

Example

| Car_ID | Car_Name | Owner |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Ferrari | Marco |
| 2 | Jeep | Enrico |
| 3 | Mercedes | Matteo |
| 1 | Ferrari | Andrea |
| 3 | Mercedes | Giorgio |
| 2 | Jeep | Gianluca |

How can i get this?

| Car_ID | Car_Name | Owners |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Ferrari | Marco,Andrea |
| 2 | Jeep | Enrico,Gianluca |
| 3 | Mercedes | Matteo,Giorgio |

I tried something but i didn't get close enough to show something here.

Comment: Update your post with what you tried, and add a tag for the corresponding dbms you're using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Need to know your DB name to suggest appropriate answer.
It's not pivot rather string aggregation. I will try to cover major RDBMs.

If you are using `sql server` or `postgres` you can use `string_agg()`

Query:

```
select Car_ID,Car_Name,string_agg(Owner,',') as Owners from Cars
group by Car_ID,Car_Name
```

Output:

| Car_ID | Car_Name | Owners |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Ferrari | Marco,Andrea |
| 2 | Jeep | Enrico,Gianluca |
| 3 | Mercedes | Matteo,Giorgio |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/NTSPsAzC)

If you are using `MySql` then you can use `group_concat()`:

Query:

```
select Car_ID,Car_Name,group_concat(Owner) as Owners from Cars
group by Car_ID,Car_Name
```

Output:

| Car_ID | Car_Name | Owners |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Ferrari | Marco,Andrea |
| 2 | Jeep | Enrico,Gianluca |
| 3 | Mercedes | Matteo,Giorgio |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ofQdN-us)

If you are using `Oracle` then you can use `listagg()` for this purpose:

Query:

```
select Car_ID,Car_Name,listagg(Owner,',') as Owners from Cars
group by Car_ID,Car_Name
```

Output:

| CAR_ID | CAR_NAME | OWNERS |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | Mercedes | Matteo,Giorgio |
| 1 | Ferrari | Marco,Andrea |
| 2 | Jeep | Enrico,Gianluca |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/oentdS6E)

Comment: omg was that simple. Thanks.

Comment: You are most welcome. As simple as it could be. Best wishes.